# Unexpected behavior from Scale

Tags: graphics, geometry

I believe the three lines drawn (or not) should be the same.  In Mathematica 10.3 they are not.

```
side = Line[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}}]
Graphics @ Scale[side, 31]
Graphics @ Scale[side, 32]
Graphics @ Scale[side, 33]
```

Oddly, numbers below 32 work fine and number above 32 do not display (without warning).

Comment: I tried it with MMA 10.4.  At first, two lines were visible.  So, I changed the magnification / zoom from 100% to 200%, scrolled down some and all 3 lines were visible.  I used the magnification button in the lower right hand corner.

Comment: The three lines should certainly not ***be*** the same. It might be correct to expect that they ***look*** the same on your screen, but the three lines certainly do not have the same end point coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

I can cast some light on what is happening by adding some options to `Graphics`.

```
Graphics[{Scale[side, 40]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: g1]

```
Graphics[{Scale[side, 40]}, PlotRangePadding -> 10, Frame -> True]
```

[image: g2]

Somehow the scaling has moved the line upwards, so it is outside the viewport in the first example. Note also the horizontal stretching is also likely not what you were expected. Probably what you really want is

```
Graphics[Scale[side, 40, {0, 0}], PlotRangePadding -> 10, Frame -> True]
```

[image: g3]

Giving `Scale` an explicit anchor point solves the problem.

```
Graphics[Scale[side, 40, {0, 0}]]
```

[image: g4]

Note: the results are sensitive to the Front End setting for magnification. The results shown here were obtained at a magnification of 125%. The work-around is good at all magnifications that I experimented with.

Comment: So ... am I right that the behavior I found is surprising or a front-end bug?  That an anchor point "fixes" it suggests so ...

Comment: @Alan. The behavior feels like a bug to me, but I don't have the confidence to categorically pronounce it to be a bug. I would like to see comments from other community members.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is also affected by [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

side = Line[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}}];

Manipulate[
 Column[
  Graphics[#, PlotRange -> {-2, ymax}] & /@
   {Scale[side, scale],
    Scale[side, scale + 1],
    Scale[side, scale + 2]}],
 {{ymax, 19, Subscript["y", "max"]}, 2, 20, 1,
  Appearance -> {"Open", "Labeled"}},
 {{scale, 31}, 2, 38, 1,
  Appearance -> {"Open", "Labeled"}}]
```

[image]